# Cannot apply unary operator `-` to type `usize`

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get some older Rust code to compile, and on this bit of code:

```
const SOMETHING: *const c_char = -1 as *const c_char;
```

I get this error:

```
error: cannot apply unary operator `-` to type `usize`
  --> src/lib.rs:32:34
   |
32 | const SOMETHING: *const c_char = -1 as *const c_char;
   |
```

I suspect this is because `c_char` is unsigned and unsigned can't be negative, but I don't know how to fix it. This code worked with some unknown older version of Rust. I tried changing `c_char` to `i8` just for fun and that didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you truly want to set a pointer to `-1`, you can, you just need to be explicit that the integral value is a `isize`, not a `usize`:

```
const SOMETHING: *const c_char = -1_isize as *const c_char;
```

You can also say that it's the maximum `usize` value:

```
const SOMETHING: *const c_char = std::usize::MAX as *const c_char;
```

Both of these have the same result:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_char;

const SOMETHING1: *const c_char = -1_isize as *const c_char;
const SOMETHING2: *const c_char = std::usize::MAX as *const c_char;

fn main() {
    println!("{:p}", SOMETHING1);
    println!("{:p}", SOMETHING2);
}
```

Prints:

```
0xffffffffffffffff
0xffffffffffffffff
```

Answer (score 9):

The type of the pointee is irrelevant. When you cast an integer to a pointer, Rust infers that the integer must be a `usize`, because it's the only type (besides `isize`, though it's not used as often) that is guaranteed to have the same size as a pointer.

Indeed, in Rust, the unary negation operator is no longer available for unsigned integer types. Instead, you should use the bitwise not operator (which is written `!`, not `~` as in C).

In two's complement binary, there is a straightforward equivalence between these two operators: `!x == -(x + 1)`. Specifically, the equivalent of `-1` is `!0`. Thus, you can write:

```
const SOMETHING: *const c_char = !0 as *const c_char;
```